# jQuery selector to target any class name (of multiple present) starting with a prefix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm considering one selection statement that would target one of many css class names in a single class attribute value based on a string prefix.

For example, I want any `detail-` prefixed class names to get targeted from the following sample links.

```
<a href="eg.html" class="detail-1 pinkify another">
<a href="eg.html" class="something detail-55 minded">
<a href="eg.html" class="swing narrow detail-Z">
<a href="eg.html" class="swing narrow detail-Z detail-88 detail-A">
```

It's reminiscent of how [`[class|="detail"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/) prefix selector works on a scalar attribute value, and also of [`.hasClass(className)`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), but my question needs both concepts applied simultaneously.

*Note:* The `detail-` prefix won't necessarily be the first class name of the bunch.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because of the way the `class` attribute is designed, you'll need to make use of at least two other attribute selectors (notice the whitespace in `[class*=" detail-"]`):

```
$('a[class^="detail-"], a[class*=" detail-"]');
```

This selects `<a>` elements with a `class` attribute that

- starts with `detail-`, or
- contains a class prefixed with `detail-`. Class names are separated by whitespace [per the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), hence the significant space character.

If you'd like to turn this into a custom selector expression, you can do this:

```
$.expr[':']['class-prefix'] = function(elem, index, match) {
    var prefix = match[3];

    if (!prefix)
        return true;

    var sel = '[class^="' + prefix + '"], [class*=" ' + prefix + '"]';
    return $(elem).is(sel);
};
```

Then select it like this:

```
$('a:class-prefix(detail-)');
```

Or if you'd like to place this in a plugin:

```
$.fn.filterClassPrefix = function(prefix) {
    if (!prefix)
        return this;

    var sel = '[class^="' + prefix + '"], [class*=" ' + prefix + '"]';
    return this.filter(sel);
};
```

Then call it like this:

```
$('a').filterClassPrefix('detail-');
```

Comment: Awesome, had no idea you could do stuff like this!

Comment: +1 Love the plugin - thanks for that additional info.  And just for kicks an implementation http://jsfiddle.net/frzay/ Yes!

Answer (score 4):

You can add your own selectors, in your case you could add a regular expression selector for attributes:

> http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Then you could do something like this:

```
$(':regex(class,(^| )detail-)')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ArtRS/1/

I came across that article somewhere on SO but I can't remember where.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write a small plugin that uses `.map()` to walk through the classes.

```
$.fn.classBeginsWith = function(str){
  return !str ? this : this.filter( function(){
    return $.map(this.className.split(' '), function(e,i){
      if (e.match(new RegExp('^' + str, 'ig'))) return 1;
    }).length;
  });
}
```

And then:

```
$('a').classBeginsWith('detail-')
```

Answer (score -2):

try wildcard selector

http://www.emadibrahim.com/2009/07/25/jquery-wildcard-selector/

Comment: Which form of it would you suggest to answer my question?