# jQuery check .hasClass('[class*="myclass-"]');

Tags: jquery

I have a series classes start myclass, like `myclass-s1`, `myclass-b10`, `myclass-ss1` etc.
Does jQuery hasClass check if class name start 'myclass-' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [is method](http://api.jquery.com/is)

```
if($('div').is('[class^=myclass]')){
//do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use plain javascript:

```
 /\bmyclass-.+\b/.test(element.className)
```

Comment: Or .matches , which is effectively 'vanilla' 'is'

Comment: This is actually the most accurate solution. While possible, it's difficult to represent a class name prefix using attribute selectors given the nature of the `class` attribute.

Comment: @Sani Huttunen: True, I was speaking in the context of this question alone. Here's a solution using attribute selectors as opposed to `className` matching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524412/jquery-selector-to-target-any-class-name-of-multiple-present-starting-with-a-p/4524477#4524477

Answer (score 1):

You can just use straight JavaScript for this:

```
if ( myElement.className.match(/\bmyclass-.*/) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

or

```
if ( $(mySelector).attr("class").match(/\bmyclass-.*/) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use below code if you want to check if class namme starts with...
 You want to check the classes that starts with myclass- ,so it would give you the number of occurrence according to your input in the alert.
    According to this the output is 2.

```
<div class="myclass-s1"></div>
<div class="myclass-b10"></div>
<div class="myclassb10"></div>

$.expr[':'].hasClassStartingWithInput = function(obj){
return ((/\bmyclass-/).test(obj.className)); //here is the input(myclass-)that you need to give
 };

 alert($('div:hasClassStartingWithInput').length);
```