# I can't make wildcard work in CSS3

Tags: css, css-selectors, wildcard

I have this html:

```
<div>
    <input class="orderrow-1" type="text"></input>
    <input class="orderrow-2" type="text"></input>
</div>
```

and this css:

```
input[class^='orderrow-']
{
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 5px 5px 6px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

I try to style all input fields with a class that begins with 'orderrow-' but above doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Edit: Sorry, above does work. The problem is that I have two casses. Like this:

```
<div>
    <input class="trigger orderrow-1" type="text"></input>
    <input class="trigger orderrow-2" type="text"></input>
</div>
```

The selector doesn't work when there is something before orderrow-1. Ideas?

Comment: It [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4jzb/). Are you sure there's nothing else affecting the styles?

Comment: classes selectors like `.orderrow-x` have higher priority than this selector. You may want to make them more specific or to add `!important` to styles

Comment: @keaukraine: No they don't. Class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes are all counted alike when calculating specificity.

Comment: @animuson Please create a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net so we can see all aspects of your case

Comment: @keaukraine: I don't need to, that's what the [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) says. But if you need proof, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eLaBh/).

Comment: @animuson: You're right. I just tried to simplify my example. Se my edit for the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your using a prefix match `^=` which means it will match the value of the class attribute (which includes ALL class names) which begin with `orderrow-` The actual value of the class attribute it 'trigger orderrow-2' if you want a wildcard selector the specification reccomends this: `*=` it looks for a value that contains the string at any point.

example:

```
input[class ^="orderrow-"], input[class *=" orderrow-"]
{
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 5px 5px 6px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
}

input.orderrow-1 {
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

it is important to note that because attributes selectors and clas selectors have the same specificity you should place the overribe **below** the attribute to ensure proper cascadence* of the styles (as per my example - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aztP/)).

**EDIT:** as per comments to use more precise selectors in the example.

[docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) see the docs for the three different wildcard selector.

*I *sometimes* make up words, but so long as you get my meaning...

Comment: First time I hear about "cascadence".

Comment: `input[class*="orderrow-"]` will also match `input.abcorderrow-1`. A better selector to use is `input[class^="orderrow-"], input[class*=" orderrow-"]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/css-selector-by-class-prefix/8588532#8588532

Answer (score 0):

it should be fine check out my code pen test of various css3 pseudo classes here http://codepen.io/jamiepaterson/pen/cADfs

The one you want is the purple text color on this test.

Comment: My bad change to * instead of ^