# CSS Target an element that could have one of many classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to target an element that could have one of many classes.
Isn't there an easier way to write the following example?  I haven't been able to find a reference, but it seems there should be a more efficient option.

```
.myTable1 a, .myTable2 a, .myTable3 a, .myTable4 a
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: have a common name for all the tables that requires this functionality and use it in  css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about computational efficiency (i.e. browser performance), then I suggest sticking with what you already have. Otherwise...

If you know the `class` attribute always starts with the substring `myTable`, you can just use an attribute selector:

```
[class^="myTable"] a
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

If you can't guarantee that you need something that's a little more complex:

```
[class^="myTable"] a, [class*=" myTable"] a
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

An explanation is offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/css-selector-by-class-prefix/8588532#8588532). If you find this syntax arcane, then I'll suggest again going with what you already have as it's the simplest.

Alternatively, modify your HTML to include a common class that you can select by. This will let you simplify your CSS even more from what you already have.

Answer (score 5):

Try -

```
table[class^=myTable] a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: This would definitely not be more efficient (performance-wise) than the selector list he has above, though I guess it would be less code.

Comment: @JasonWyatt Agree, but I think the "efficiency" here is not about the actual selector performance, but an *"easier way to write the following example"*

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not an easier way in plain CSS.

However if your many classes are all similar, you can do fuzzy matching like this `*[class^="myTable"] { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use multiple classes in the tables that need underlined links.

**HTML**:

```
<table class="myTable1 ul_table">...</table>
<table class="myTable2 ul_table">...</table>
<table class="myTable3 ul_table">...</table>
<table class="myTable4 ul_table">...</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
.ul_table a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: This is probably the better approach to my overall problem. Thank you.  For the sake of allowing the question itself to be answered, a solution like this is probably more acceptable. `[class^=myTable]`