# How to get all classes with a specific prefix in css?

Tags: css, class, css-selectors, prefix

I know we can do this matching attributes with: `div[class*=something]` but I don't want the attribute prefix but the class prefix, like: `.icon-[something]`.

Is there some way to get all classes with a specific prefix in css?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/css-selector-by-class-prefix

Comment: I couldn't find that question, that was useful, thanks.