# CSS Class Attribute Selector with hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

is this not possible or do I have a syntax error?

I've tried it multiple ways, but nothing worked.

I have some divs using the classes `works1`, `works2`, etc..

and I want to define a general hover effect, but the result is, that exactly nothing happens when I try to make it "general"

This is my approach, any hints?

```
div[class^="works"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: grayscale(0);

  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

The classes are used like this:

`<div class="item col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 java works1"></div>`
.
.
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your `works1` class appears somewhere other than the very start of the `class` attribute, so your attribute selector won't work.

You can either move the class name to the front of the attribute value, or give your elements a common class so you can use a regular class selector.

Or, if you can't modify your HTML at all, use this instead (but I would strongly recommend changing your markup if you can):

```
div[class*=" works"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: grayscale(0);

  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/css-selector-by-class-prefix/8588532#8588532) for an explanation.

Comment: Ah thanks for the clarification. I will move the works classes to the front. Using the * also worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's the position of the `work*` in the `class` attribute, use * instead of ^ here is an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="works1">1</div>
<div class="works2 qq">2</div>
<div class="aa works3">3</div>
<div class="aa works3 qq">4</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div[class*="works"]:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/lowamalu/1/