# Selecting elements by name with wildcards

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Whats a good way to select elements by their name using wildcards?

The website has element names in the form of `<a_1786439></a_1786439>` which are likely auto-generated. This is doable by xpath, but is it doable using css selectors or jquery selectors which are faster?

This is clearly terrible-coding, but the website is not mine, and I'm writing a userscript for it.

Comment: can you please share what have you tried so far?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I use css & jquery selectors often, and if I know of a way I wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/css-selector-by-class-prefix/8588532#8588532

Comment: @DOCASAREL This is __not__ an attribute.

Comment: Dude, fiddle: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5110337/2672018.

Comment: @DOCASAREL I need wildcards in the node name, __not__ node attributes.

Comment: Can please somebody! You want "Selecting elements by name with wildcards". By chance this is called an `attribute selector`. Do you want to solve it or philosoph about wording?

Comment: @DOCASAREL https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeName

Comment: Ah, you want to "Get elements` names with wildcards"?

Comment: Why do you assume a selector will be faster than XPath? In any case, if the elements with auto-generated names represent similar items, there's a chance they have something else in common that you can select by. Perhaps some sample markup can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't exist in CSS3, as the [spec's section on type selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors) only includes names and wildcards, but no combinations of them.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create custom elements using the HTML DOM createElement method like this:

```
document.createElement('Funny_Element');
```

In the website code you are dealing with, they have created a custom element, or maybe extend the `a` element, but they didn't choose a significant name! `a_1786439`??? which is, I think, really bad.

Using CSS selectors or jQuery selectors depends essentially on what you want to do. Suppose you have to access children elements of a specific node, then jquery selectors would be more appropriate.

Hope it's useful!