# Find element by exact text within the exact element using css selector

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I wonder if I could match an element by exact text via css-locators (The overall goal is to use it as a locator for `Selenium`). I know the `contains` method

**For example:**

```
<div><div>S - Subscriber</div></div>
```

I can retrieve it by `css=div:contains('Subscriber')` or by `css=div:contains('S - Subscriber')` but I need exact match. I tried `css=div:contains('^S - Subscriber$')` and this element is not found.

**One more point:**

When we use `xpath` we can assume that given text is in exact element by retrieving text with `text()` function (for example `//div[text()='S - Subscriber']` will point us exactly to the child div, whenever `//div[contains(., 'S - Subscriber')]` will point us to the parent div, if i am not messed up), so is there equivalent in css another way then `css=div > div:contains('S - Subscriber')` ? I mean pointing just one element, without parent div.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/make-jquerys-contains-select-only-exact-string

Comment: i don't need it in jquery, I need css-selector to use it in Selenium. So css=div[text='S - Subscriber'] - not found, css=div[text()='S - Subscriber'] - not found, can you advise how to build it to use as element description for Selenium? Updated the question, but i thought tags will be informative

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using selenium I would just go with using Xpath instead. You'll get the element you want with the following: `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[text()="S - Subscriber"]')`

Sadly you can't use css selectors for what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes, i know that :) i have that xpath in my question, but i was querin about css locator, due to it's 'faster', etc..

Comment: I missed that :) But it seems like CSS Selectors doesn't support what you're trying to do. Read the highest voted comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t

Comment: So then you're question is answered :) I would be grateful if you marked it as such :)

Comment: Votin up, because maybe someday someone will come up with solution :)

Comment: What's up with people straight-up assuming that a CSS selector would be faster than XPath? This is the [second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867922/selecting-elements-by-name-with-wildcards#comment40482150_25867922) I've heard it this week. So what if it's faster if there isn't even a solution? Are you going to refuse to use a readily-available alternative *just because it's slower* (than a *non-existent* solution for crying out loud)?

Comment: @BoltClock, sorry, but where have you read that i am refusing to use xpath here? I AM using it, but i was wondering if i could do the same with css. No reason to be critic here.

Comment: and yes, if something does not exist today, doesn't mean that it will not occur tomorrow, when somebody will open this question and tell "hey mate, this is how you can do it"

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regex for exact matching.

```
var r = /^a$/;
css=a:contains((r.test('Text')) ? 'Text' : '');
```