# CSS pipe selector with multiple classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

Suppose I have two elements with multiple classes:

```
<p class="fruit-apple something">First</p>
<p class="whatever fruit-banana">Second</p>
```

How can I use the “pipe” selector (`|=`) to select the `fruit-` classes?

I have tried something like the following but this seems not to work.

```css
p[class|=fruit] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="fruit-apple something">First</p>
<p class="whatever fruit-banana">Second</p>
```

This is clearly because in the second case, the class string does not begin with `fruit-`, and the selector is matching naively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector by class prefix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix)

Comment: @dotnetom Not quite, but nearly — @SBUJOLD’s answer does, however appear to be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `|=` selector only selects the [*starting* portion](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) of the specified attribute.

You'll want the `*=` operator instead.

`p[class*=fruit-]`

It will search for classes that contain the phrase `fruit-x` where `x` is anything you want.

```css
p[class*=fruit-] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="fruit-apple something">First</p>
<p class="whatever fruit-banana">Second</p>
<p class="whatever fruit">Third (No selection)</p>
<p class="fruit noselect">Fourth (No selection)</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is how it appears, which I think is a weakness in the available selectors. The only problem with this solution is that this selector will also be satisfied with partial matches such as `not-fruit-donut`, but maybe that’s getting picky.

Comment: @Manngo There's definitely some flaws in the CSS selectors. In a situation like the one you suggested with `not-fruit-donut`, you could duplicate the CSS and reverse the color: `p[class*=-fruit] { color: black; }`. It's far from elegant, but it is a practical solution to that specific problem.

Comment: @Manngo: That's why someone else recommended my answer to the linked question earlier on - it accounts for most, if not all, possible scenarios, including the one you mention, without requiring an overriding rule.