# CSS - p::first-letter:not does not work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have to increase the size of the first letter of every `P` elements that are not `class="ejemplo"` or `id="lectura"`.

This works perfectly:

```
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

But when I try to match the requirements and I do this, it doesn't work:

```
p::first-letter:not([class="ejemplo"]):not([id="lectura"]) {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

I'm beginner in CSS, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pseudo element `::first-letter` must come last in your statement:

***Order DOES matter:***

[**MDN's docs:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

> You can use only one pseudo-element in a selector. **It must appear after** the simple selectors in the statement.

So:

```css
p:not([class="ejemplo"]):not([id="lectura"])::first-letter {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<p>Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
<p class="ejemplo">Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
<p id="lectura">Loren Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
```

**Also...**

Remember that for id selection, use `#id` instead of `[id='']`, and `.class` instead of `[class='']`

```
p:not(.ejemplo):not(#lectura)::first-letter {
```

Comment: @torazaburo: For pseudo-elements it does seem to. Please try the selector as provided in question and it doesn't work.

Comment: @torazaburo did you even try to run the code snippet?

Comment: Its there in the official spec also - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements

Comment: @LcSalazar it worked! But what if instead of just 1 class to not apply the style I would have 2 or more? Is there something like `not(.ejemplo||.ejemplo2||.ejemplo3)` or should I repeat the `:not` selector for every class?

Comment: @Drumnbass: As far as I know `:not` can't take complex selectors, so you'll more than likely have to repeat it.

Comment: @Drumnbass - Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
p:not([class="ejemplo"]):not([id="lectura"])::first-letter {
```

Instead:

```
p::first-letter:not([class="ejemplo"]):not([id="lectura"]) {
```

Comment: @torazaburo This is the same answer that the others, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You should add `::first-letter` at last

```css
p:not(.ejemplo):not(#lectura)::first-letter{
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<p>test</p>
<p id="lectura">test</p>
<p class="ejemplo">test</p>
```