# How to apply a rule to all classes starting with a specific word?

Tags: css

I want to apply:

```
.page-item-124 a {
  font-size: 15px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

to all page items (classes starting with `page-item`) there are.

How can I do that?

Comment: `font-size` is inherit property. so apply only to `body` tag. and no need of `!important`.

Comment: OP said: `to all page items`. I hope he meant to all elements in that page.

Comment: As the class  name is `page-item-xxx` I assumed he meant the elements with class `page-item-[something]` ;) btw; we can't know if `!important` is needed. Probably he's overwriting template styles.

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted to do @giorgio :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector by class prefix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 [attribute*=value] Selector like this

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/180/

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-item-1">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="page-item-2">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div[class*="page-item"] {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also How does accepting an answer work?

Comment: If you want to use same class on other html element for example `a` your css selector  should be like this `a[class*="page-item"]` but since you are using `div` you can use this selector `div[class*="page-item"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the starts with (`^=`) or wildcard (`*=`) attribute selector for that:

```
[class=^page-item] { font-size: 15px !important; font-weight: bold; }
```

This will select among others these elements:

```
<p class="page-item-123"></p>
<section class="page-item-intro"></section>
```

You might want to narrow it down a bit. Eg only select `div` elements.

```
div[class^=page-item] { ... }
```

See also [selector documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3mfLv6gq/)