# How to select element in javascript whose name starts with some particular string?

Tags: javascript, variables, classname, startswith

I want a javascript code which will select the element whose class name begins with the string "*bzeytq*". Maybe the full class name is "*bzeytqsXAl0a4TF2EK1PC _3cTEY2txA4EJKTiaTADaE*", but I want to store the starting of the class name as a search variable, and use the search variable to find elements by class name.

Something like this :

```
search_str = "bzeytq"
itemName = document.querySelectorAll(search_str )[0].innerText;
```

It should select the element with full class name as "*bzeytqsXAl0a4TF2EK1PC _3cTEY2txA4EJKTiaTADaE*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector by class prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix)

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not the suggested duplicate fully addresses your question?

Comment: `querySelectorAll('[class^="'+search_str+'"]')`

Comment: a) Highly recommend using jQuery - makes this kind of thing a lot easier. b) Why not have 2 classes - one for the search term - e.g., "bzeytq" and another for the full detailed class name? Or have the full detailed item be the ID? The general concept is to have the class name be repeated - which makes it great for group searches (in jQuery - $('.bzeytq')....) and to have the IDs be truly unique.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery to target specific class with following syntax $('.className')