# CSS Short-hand for Multiple Arbitrary Children

Tags: css, css-selectors

In CSS, if I want to style 3 sub-classes of a given class, is there a short-hand way of doing that in a manner where the root class does not have to be repeated for each sub-class?

For example, let say I have this html:

```
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="subClass1">Sub-Class-1</div>
    <div class="subClass2">Sub-Class-2</div>
    <div class="subClass3">Sub-Class-3</div>
    <div class="subClass4">Sub-Class-4</div>
    <div class="subClass5">Sub-Class-5</div>
    <div class="subClass6">Sub-Class-6</div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
    <div class="subClass1">Sub-Class-1</div>
    <div class="subClass2">Sub-Class-2</div>
    <div class="subClass3">Sub-Class-3</div>
    <div class="subClass4">Sub-Class-4</div>
    <div class="subClass5">Sub-Class-5</div>
    <div class="subClass6">Sub-Class-6</div>
</div>
```

I want to make sub-classes 1, 3, 6 of **parent1** red (without effecting the **parent2** sub-classes). The way I'd do this is in CSS is:

```
.parent1 .subClass1,
.parent1 .subClass3,
.parent1 .subClass6
{
    color: red;
}
```

Is there a syntax in CSS where I can do something like this instead:

```
.parent1 (.subClass1, .subClass3, .subClass6)
{
    color: red;
}
```

... so that the **parent1** class only has to be typed once?

Comment: No, not in CSS. You might want to look into CSS preprocessors such as LESS or SASS.

Comment: In navitve CSS, no. In a precompiler like LESS or SASS, yes, as you can do `.class1 { .class2, .class3, .class3 { /* styles */ } }`

Comment: I wonder can't you just use `nth-child` on this.

Comment: Of course, for multiple `parentX` classes, you could use the attribute selector to target all elements with a class that _starts with_ `parent` in one go ... (https://stackoverflow.com/q/3338680/1427878)

Comment: [:matches](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/)

Comment: In fact, it is in [Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches): `.parent1 :matches(.subClass1, .subClass3, .subClass6)`. Unfortunately, it works currently only in Safari.

Comment: Ah, :matches is exactly what I'm looking for. I will [wait for support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-matches-pseudo).

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you describe, but in your specific example you can use `nth-child` to style every odd child:

```
.parent1 div:nth-child(odd) {

}
```

Or if each of the classes you want to target has text in common you can use an attribute selector:

```
.parent1 div[class*=subClass] {

}
```

That would target all children of parent1 that has `subClass` somewhere in its class. So in your case would select all children.

Comment: I've edited my question to emphasize that I'm after an arbitrary selection (where "odd" won't work).