# How can I DRY this css rule

Tags: css

Is there a way to write a rule set equivalent to the following while only using one `.active` selector?

```
.active #pselect,
.active #bselect,
.active #cselect,
.active #nselect,
.active #iselect {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: it looks like you really need to add a class to all of your active elements and select for that class

Comment: use a class instead after-all, that's what they're for.  Also it stops you from getting into specificity nightmares

Comment: You would use a class instead of ids to apply the `color: $white` Maybe add your html so we can better see what's going on. a [mcve] always helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector by class prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix)

Comment: @TylerH Even though the answers are similar, this is a distinctly different problem than the question you referenced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally you would add a class to the elements you're selecting by id. But if that's not possible, you could use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
.active [id$="select"] {
  color: white;
}
```

This particular attribute selector selects all elements with an id value that ends with "select".