# There is the possibility of placing a * to specify that apply a characteristic to all objects

Tags: html, css

Example

```css
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 > div { background: #441102; border: 1px solid #1efe52; }
```

I try to do this, apply something similar to a regular expression.

```css
    .col-lg-* ,.col-sm-* > div { background: #441102; border: 1px solid #1efe52; }
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such possibility.

An asterisk (`*`) by itself, with spaces around it, means: "match any single element". It is not a wildcard like in a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) expression (and definitely not like in a regular expression).

If you want to match on complex text expressions (not simple matching by string equality), then CSS3 has some additional matching rules to help you do that - for example, see this other Stack Overflow question: [Is there a CSS selector by class prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3338680/53538)