# How do I apply a scss property to all classes that have a common prefix?

Tags: css, sass

i have few dynamic classes dynamicClass1,dynamicClass2,dynamicClass3, ... ,dynamicClassN

I want to apply a common css property to all of them in my .scss file.

Approach I followed -

```
dynamicClass {
  &* {
        display: grid;
  }
}
```

This isn't working. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to do something like this:

```css
[class^="dynamicClass"], [class*=" dynamicClass"] {
  display: grid;
}
```

Based on this answer:
[Is there a CSS selector by class prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix)