# CSS for Indirect Children (of multiple type) of Elements whose ID beings with XYZ

Tags: html, css

I have two sections (divs each containing multiple levels of divs below) within a webpage.  Each top level section id begins either:

- idTaskControls_
- idTaskItem_

> ```
> <div id='idTaskControls'>
>     <div id='idTaskControlsHeader'>
>        <div>Header</div>
>     </div>
>     <div id='idTaskControlsContent'>
>        <input id='idTaskControlsContentPriority'>
>     </div>
> </div>
> <div id='idTaskItem>
>     <div id='idTaskItemHeader'>
>        <div>Header</div>
>     </div>
>     <div id='idTaskItemContent'>
>        <input id='idTaskItemContentPriority'>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

I want to apply a different style to all input, select, text area in each section.  I've tried:

```
[name*="idTaskControls_"] input, textarea, select {
background: none;
border: solid thin grey;
border-bottom: solid medium grey;   
}
```

and

```
[name*="idTaskItem_"] input, textarea, select {
background: none;
border-top: solid thin lightgray;
border-bottom: solid thin lightgray;
border-left: solid medium grey;
border-right: solid thin lightgray;  
}
```

but, for every input, textarea, select in both sections, both styles appear in the F12 inspector. Some elements have the correct style, others do not.

Should these styles work as I explained above, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use something like div[id^="idTask-"] or div[id*=" idTask-"] this. Reeference. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix).

Comment: @Nikkkshit that will pick up every single element that beings/contains 'idTask-', I only want the editable elements (textarea, input, select) to be affected.

Comment: Please re-open this question, I understand what commas do, but this does not help me.

Comment: I dont' Know but (div[id*="idTaskItem"] input) and (div[id*="idTaskControls"] input) both selectors are working well Take look at this pen [link](https://codepen.io/nexo12/pen/abWGOoK)

Comment: @Nikkkshit I worked it out, I was expecting "input, select, textarea" to include all of that type that belong to any filtered IDs.  It did for input, but for select and textarea it included EVERY instance on the whole page. I needed to repeat the main selector three times and include one of each input, select, textarea for each.

Comment: don't add answer in the question, the duplicate already answer your question by explaining how comma and space works inside a selector which is your mistake here

Comment: @temani afif please don't change my question. The link did not explain sufficiently how to fix my issue. This was specifically about multiple child types as much as the comma.

Comment: whatever the question, it should remain a *question*. If you don't agree with the duplicate vote to reopen and if it get reopened add an answer. Don't change your question to make it an answer.