# CSS Selector to identify first and last element of groups with part of same class

Tags: css

I have a list of products which can be in a bundle. I want to draw a border around each product which is part of the same bundle.

```
<ul>
   <li class="bundle-1">Product 1</li>
   <li class="bundle-1">Product 2</li>
   <li class="bundle-2">Product A</li>
   <li class="bundle-2">Product B</li>
   <li>Product I</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

The border is around Product 1 & 2 and Product A & B.
Exist a CSS Selector to group some elements?

```
[class*="bundle-"] {
   border-left: 1px solid blue;
   border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
[class*="bundle-"]:first-child {
   border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
[class*="bundle-"]:last-child {
   border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Will they gonna be in same sequence everytime?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in css if you can't change the structure, you'll need JS

Comment: @Nikkkshit yes the order is the same.

Comment: only 2 bundles or they can be many ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix

Comment: It's impossible to select last-child of a specific class. It will always be the last child of the parent.

Comment: Here is a [pen](https://codepen.io/cedricbeausseron/pen/vYRybMq) with a structure that could work for your needs