# How do I filter the text, "positivity" preserving parents and children?

Tags: javascript

How do I filter the text, "positivity" preserving parents and children. Note that the parents and children are in ascending order. Example if you have 'class child-1' is a child child-2 is another child and so on. When you have a child-0 class followed by another child-0, the first child-0 class has no children. Pure javascript please. Thanks in advance.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-BR">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">   
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="searchFilter" name="searchFilter" placeholder="Search" 
                       onkeyup="filterItems(this);">
                <select id="help-my-brother" name="ddVehicles" size="4">
                    <option value="-1">None</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="1">United States</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="2">Australia</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="3">Brazil</option>
                    <option class="child-1" value="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Iceland</option>
                    <option class="child-2" value="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;UK</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="6">Germany</option>
                    <option class="child-1" value="7">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Italy</option>
                    <option class="child-2" value="8">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;France</option>
                    <option class="child-3" value="9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;China</option>
                    <option class="child-4" value="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;positivity</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="11">Japan</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="12">Argentina</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="13">Colombia</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="14">Mexico</option> 
                    <option class="child-0" value="15">Chile</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="16">Venezuela</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="17">Peace and love</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="18">Florida</option>
                    <option class="child-1" value="19">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hug</option>
                    <option class="child-2" value="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Action</option>
                    <option class="child-3" value="21">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Adaptable</option>
                    <option class="child-4" value="22">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;positivity</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="23">Love</option>
                    <option class="child-1" value="24">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;charisma</option>
                    <option class="child-2" value="25">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Charm</option>
                    <option class="child-3" value="26">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;positivity</option>
                    <option class="child-4" value="27">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Friend</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="28">Peru</option>
                    <option class="child-1" value="29">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;clarity</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="30">collaboration</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="31">companionship</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="32">Communication</option>
                    <option class="child-0" value="33">reliable</option>
                </select>
            </form>
    
            <script>
    
                var optionsCache = [];
    
                function filterItems(el) {
                    var value = el.value.toLowerCase();
                    var form = el.form;
                    var opt, sel = form.ddVehicles;
                    if (value == '') {
                        restoreOptions();
                    } else {
                        // Loop backwards through options as removing them modifies the next
                        // to be visited if go forwards
                        for (var i = sel.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            opt = sel.options[i];
                            if (opt.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) == -1) {
                                sel.removeChild(opt)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    
    // Restore select to original state
                function restoreOptions() {
                    var sel = document.getElementById('help-my-brother');
                    sel.options.length = 0;
                    for (var i = 0, iLen = optionsCache.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                        sel.appendChild(optionsCache[i]);
                    }
                }
    
    
                window.onload = function () {
                    // Load cache
                    var sel = document.getElementById('help-my-brother');
                    for (var i = 0, iLen = sel.options.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                        optionsCache.push(sel.options[i]);
                    }
                }
    
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The result in the search for "positivity" has to be this:

```
<form>
            <input type="text" id="searchFilter" name="searchFilter" placeholder="Search" 
                   onkeyup="filterItems(this);">
            <select id="help-my-brother" name="ddVehicles" size="4">
                <option class="child-0" value="6">Germany</option>
                <option class="child-1" value="7">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Italy</option>
                <option class="child-2" value="8">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;France</option>
                <option class="child-3" value="9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;China</option>
                <option class="child-4" value="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;positivity</option>
                <option class="child-0" value="18">Florida</option>
                <option class="child-1" value="19">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hug</option>
                <option class="child-2" value="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Action</option>
                <option class="child-3" value="21">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Adaptable</option>
                <option class="child-4" value="22">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;positivity</option>
                <option class="child-0" value="23">Love</option>
                <option class="child-1" value="24">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;charisma</option>
                <option class="child-2" value="25">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Charm</option>
                <option class="child-3" value="26">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;positivity</option>
                <option class="child-4" value="27">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Friend</option>
            </select>
        </form>
```

Comment: The best solution would be to modify your html to make filtering easier.  The standard solution would use [optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) elements to group associated items. Yet, if that's not possible then use class names that indicate the relationships, e.g., child-1-2 where 1 is the group and 2 the child index. With these class names you could then [select by prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear to me what you want to do once you've classified each option element, but at any rate...

You can use the function `findMatchingOptions` below to classify each option: Provide an array of the options elements to it, and it will return an array of objects of type:

```ts
{
  element: HTMLElement;
  isValid: boolean;
}
```

You can use the `isValid` property to do whatever you need to do (e.g. [hide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden) the invalid ones). I've enumerated the results in the console output for demonstration.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="searchFilter" name="searchFilter" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="filterItems(this);">
  <select id="help-my-brother" name="ddVehicles" size="4">
    <option value="-1">None</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="1">United States</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="2">Australia</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="3">Brazil</option>
    <option class="child-1" value="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Iceland</option>
    <option class="child-2" value="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;UK</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="6">Germany</option>
    <option class="child-1" value="7">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Italy</option>
    <option class="child-2" value="8">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;France</option>
    <option class="child-3" value="9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;China</option>
    <option class="child-4" value="10">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;positivity</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="11">Japan</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="12">Argentina</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="13">Colombia</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="14">Mexico</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="15">Chile</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="16">Venezuela</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="17">Peace and love</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="18">Florida</option>
    <option class="child-1" value="19">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hug</option>
    <option class="child-2" value="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Action</option>
    <option class="child-3" value="21">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Adaptable</option>
    <option class="child-4" value="22">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;positivity</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="23">Love</option>
    <option class="child-1" value="24">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;charisma</option>
    <option class="child-2" value="25">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Charm</option>
    <option class="child-3" value="26">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;positivity</option>
    <option class="child-4" value="27">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Friend
    </option>
    <option class="child-0" value="28">Peru</option>
    <option class="child-1" value="29">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;clarity</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="30">collaboration</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="31">companionship</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="32">Communication</option>
    <option class="child-0" value="33">reliable</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script type="module">

const childClassRegexp = /^child-(\d+)$/;

/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} element
 * @returns {number | undefined}
 */
function findChildNumber (element) {
  const className = [...element.classList].find(
    className => childClassRegexp.test(className)
  );
  return className ? Number(className.slice(6)) : undefined;
}

/**
 * @param {Array<HTMLElement>} elements
 * @param {string | undefined} filterTextContent
 * @returns {Array<{ element: HTMLElement; isValid: boolean }>}
 */
function findMatchingOptions (elements, filterTextContent = 'positivity') {
  /** @type {Array<{ element: HTMLElement; isValid: boolean }>} */
  const results = [];
  
  /** @type {Array<HTMLElement>} */
  const candidates = [];
  let previousChildNumber = -1;

  const evaluateCandidates = () => {
    const isValid = candidates
      .some(element => element.textContent?.includes(filterTextContent));
    for (const element of candidates) results.push({element, isValid});
    candidates.length = 0;
  };

  for (const element of elements) {
    const childNumber = findChildNumber(element);

    if (childNumber !== previousChildNumber + 1) {
      evaluateCandidates();
      previousChildNumber = -1;

      if (typeof childNumber !== 'number') {
        results.push({element, isValid: false});
        continue;
      }
    }

    candidates.push(element);
    previousChildNumber += 1;
  }

  evaluateCandidates();
  return results;
}

function main () {
  const optionElements =
    [...document.querySelectorAll('select#help-my-brother > option')];

  const results = findMatchingOptions(optionElements);

  for (const {element, isValid} of results) {
    element.hidden = !isValid; // Hide the invalid ones

    console.log(
      isValid ? '✅' : '❌',
      findChildNumber(element),
      element.textContent.trim(),
    );
  }
}

main();

</script>
```